# eslint - webpack aliases

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I have a webpack configuration file, which is actually a factory function (`react-universally` boilerplate).

I've added `resolve` option and it looks like this:

```
resolve: {
      // These extensions are tried when resolving a file.
      extensions: config('bundleSrcTypes').map(ext => `.${ext}`),

      // This is required for the modernizr-loader
      // @see https://github.com/peerigon/modernizr-loader
      alias: {
        modernizr$: path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), './.modernizrrc'),
        Config: path.resolve(appRootDir.get(), './config'),
      },
    },
```

With this config I'm able to access the reducers like `import config from 'Config'`, but my linter is throwing me errors:

```
'Config' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S Config' to add it (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
'Config' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S Config' to add it (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
Missing file extension for "Config" (import/extensions)
```

How can I add aliases to my eslinter configuration? I've tried several packages listed in the top google results for this problem, but they do not work. Is it possible to add the aliases to the `.eslintrc` manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can list your aliases through the `import/core-modules` option under settings.

in your .eslintrc

```
"settings": {
  "import/core-modules": [
    "config-alias",
    "another-alias"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the config import is a special exception, you can tell ESLint to ignore that line (for all rules or just a single rule)

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

Comment: Yes, but disabling it for the amount of file I have in the project is just a nightmare, as there are many more aliases like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` rule has a whitelist or blacklist option for specific packages. You might want to open an issue on Github for the plugin.